# error on PDO connection to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to connect to a database using PDO but I'm getting this error message:

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I'm using `mamp` and thanks for the help

Php code:

```
<?php
$dsn ="mysql: host=local host:8888; dbname=fruit";
$username="root";
$password="my password";
Try{
$conn= new PDO($dsn,$username,$password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO:ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Connection failed: ".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: `$conn->setAttribute(PDO:ATTR_ERRMODE` <- forgot 1x `:` also don't write spaces in the `$dsn` string

Comment: its funny because having that space between `local<space>host` on my env works. lol. but fix it anyway including the PDO constant typo like the comment above ^

Comment: @Ghost Really? That's interesting, I get: `Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed` What env do you have?

Comment: @Rizier123 really odd, works fine having that space `PHP 5.4.34-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Oct 17 2014 15:28:55)` with `PDO mysqlnd 5.0.10 `

Comment: @Rizier123 to clarify `$dsn ="mysql:<space>host=local host:8888;` this still works, but this doesn't `$dsn ="mysql:host=local host:8888;` (without the space after colon), odd, but it defaults to localhost

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
<?php
$dsn ="mysql:host=localhost:8888;dbname=fruit";
$username="root";
$password="my password";
Try{
$conn= new PDO($dsn,$username,$password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Connection failed: ".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry guys first I'm a bigginer second I wrote those code same as it is written in the book and didn't work so I asked but anyway I got it working but coderunner still shows that error but when I try it on browser I been able to get data from that database so all good I guess and I used my phone to write those code so it's little bit hard. But thanks anyway